# How does mysql maintain ibd file?

Tags: mysql

Will mysql load whole ibd file into memory and handle all things in memory when inserting new lines to innodb?

The data size may be quite big, so the primary index may not be loaded to memory.

The secondary index only link to primary index, which means the secondary index may not be quite huge. So, why not load all the secondary index to memory and update in memory only unless flushing to disk is required.

If the secondary index can be loaded to memory, why B tree must be used?

Comment: Your question does not read well, it's extremely hard to understand.  If English isn't your first language, please try to have someone assist you in making it more comprehensible?

Comment: The unit of "load into buffer_pool" is one block of 16KB, not whole tables or whole indexes.

Answer (score 1):

No, only a subset of pages of the .ibd file are loaded into memory. The pages loaded are those that are examined by the queries you run. As you run other queries, this may cause the least recently used pages to be evicted.

This is all described here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-buffer-pool.html

It's not necessary to load all secondary indexes into memory, if your queries don't use those indexes, or use only part of the index.

You don't need to specify BTREE as the index type for InnoDB tables. InnoDB indexes are BTREE by default. InnoDB does not support the HASH index type, so there's no need to specify BTREE. Other index types supported by InnoDB are FULLTEXT or SPATIAL, but that's all.

Comment: (If you were using MariaDB, I would add that `TEXT` columns can be HASH-indexed.)